# Live Template btnClick en Android Studio 2.1

Tags: android-studio

Me estoy acostumbrando a usar los live templates que lleva Android Studio.
`ctrl+j`: se muestran los disponibles.

Intento crear un Live Template que se inicie, escribiendo `btnClick`, la finalidad es para completar código de asignación de un evento click a un botón.

Código live template en xml:

```
<templateSet group="Android">
  <template name="btnClick" value="Button $var0$ = (Button) findViewById(R.id.$var1$);&#10;if ($var0$ != null) {&#10;    $var0$.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {&#10;&#10;        @Override&#10;        public void onClick(View v) {&#10;            //TODO click Event&#10;            $END$&#10;        }&#10;    });&#10;}" description="Generate Click Button Event" toReformat="false" toShortenFQNames="true">
    <variable name="var0" expression="" defaultValue="" alwaysStopAt="true" />
    <variable name="var1" expression="complete()" defaultValue="" alwaysStopAt="true" />
    <context>
      <option name="JAVA_CODE" value="false" />
      <option name="JAVA_STATEMENT" value="true" />
      <option name="JAVA_EXPRESSION" value="false" />
      <option name="JAVA_DECLARATION" value="false" />
      <option name="JAVA_COMMENT" value="false" />
      <option name="JAVA_STRING" value="false" />
      <option name="COMPLETION" value="false" />
    </context>
  </template>
</templateSet>
```

**comando:** `btnClick`

**código:**

```
Button $var0$ = (Button) findViewById(R.id.$var1$);
if ($var0$ != null) {
    $var0$.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //TODO click Event
            $END$
        }
    });
}
```

**Declaración de variables**

`$var0$` nada *intento que se muestre por defecto myButton1, si el usuario no modifica nada

`$var1%` => acción completar, para que se muestre un lista de los ids del layout.

**Aplicable en**: Java: Statement

No ser si es posible definir un valor por defecto en $var0$ con el texto `myBtn1` en caso que no se modifique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intentando poner el texto myBtn1 por defecto en el atributo defaultValue de la var0, sin éxito, me puesto a buscar documentación de la live tempaltes.

1. [Cómo crear live templates (en)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html?origin=old_help)
2. [Acciones en variables (en)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/creating-and-editing-template-variables.html)

La solución:
Para especificar literales se debe usar `"`

La definición de la `$var0$` en la live template

```
... defaultValue="&quot;my_Button1&quot;" ...
```

template final:

```
<templateSet group="Android">
  <template name="btnClick" value="Button $var0$ = (Button) findViewById(R.id.$var1$);&#10;if ($var0$ != null) {&#10;    $var0$.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {&#10;&#10;        @Override&#10;        public void onClick(View v) {&#10;            //TODO click Event&#10;            $END$&#10;        }&#10;    });&#10;}" description="Generate Click Button Event" toReformat="false" toShortenFQNames="true">
    <variable name="var0" expression="" defaultValue="&quot;my_Button1&quot;" alwaysStopAt="true" />
    <variable name="var1" expression="complete()" defaultValue="" alwaysStopAt="true" />
    <context>
      <option name="JAVA_CODE" value="false" />
      <option name="JAVA_STATEMENT" value="true" />
      <option name="JAVA_EXPRESSION" value="false" />
      <option name="JAVA_DECLARATION" value="false" />
      <option name="JAVA_COMMENT" value="false" />
      <option name="JAVA_STRING" value="false" />
      <option name="COMPLETION" value="false" />
    </context>
  </template>
</templateSet>
```